# Convert container component implicitly created with `connect()` to explicit container component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have this stateless functional component called `Volume` that uses `connect()` to create the container component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  volume: state.get('volume')
})

let Volume = (props) => {
  if (props.volume === 'Infinity') {
    return (
      <Text
        style={{ ...formStyles.text, ...styles.text }}>
        Incalculable
      </Text>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <Text
        style={{ ...formStyles.text, ...styles.text }}>
        {props.volume + ' litres'}
      </Text>
    )
  }
}

Volume.propTypes = {
  volume: React.PropTypes.string
}

Volume = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(Volume)

export default Volume
```

I now need to implement `componentDidMount` lifecycle method on it which will run a function that takes the whole redux store as an argument, then dispatch an action to update the `store.volume`, which can then be passed to the initial Volume presentational component to display. So I want to go back to basics and not use `connect()` so that I can implement the lifecycle method in the container component. I have never not used `connect()`

Here is my attempt:

```
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { formStyles } from '../../style'
import calcVol from '../../calcVol'
import { updateVolume } from '../../actions/updateDimension.action'

export class VolumeContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.context
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
      this.forceUpdate()
    )
    let litres = calcVol(store)
    store.dispatch(updateVolume(litres))
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe()
  }

  render() {
    const { store } = this.context
    return (
      <VolumePresentational volume={store.getState().volume} />
    )
  }
}

VolumeContainer.contextTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object
}

let VolumePresentational = (props) => {
  if (props.volume === 'Infinity') {
    return (
      <Text
        style={{ ...formStyles.text, ...styles.text }}>
        Incalculable
      </Text>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <Text
        style={{ ...formStyles.text, ...styles.text }}>
        {props.volume + ' litres'}
      </Text>
    )
  }
}

VolumePresentational.propTypes = {
  volume: React.PropTypes.string
}

const styles = {
  text: {
    marginTop: 20,
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
}

export default VolumeContainer
```

The code is getting inside my volCalc(store) function where it has the error:

> state.get is not a function

so my store that i'm passing into calcVol() in componentDidMount must not be the store.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why you would pull some store data into the component (`volume`), modify it there when the component mounts, and then dispatch it back to the store?  What is the `calcVol` function doing?

Comment: @AlexYoung calcVol calculates the volume, given the store. The app is quite maths oriented so the store only contains things needed for performing calculations. I want to do an initial calculation when the app first starts up which will calculate and display the volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if something can be calculated entirely from the state, (i.e. it is a function of that state), then it should not be in state itself.  For example, a state such as:

```
{
    x: 3,
    y: 2,
    z: 5,
    volume: 30
}
```

This results in duplication of information within the state, and ultimately all sorts of non-trivial issues with keeping things in sync with each other.  The common theme throughout React and Redux should be having a "single source of truth" i.e. information lives in one place and one place only.  In the above example, the information about volume is being stored in the `volume` property, but also in the combination of the `x`, `y` and `z` properties - so there are now two sources of truth.

In terms of applying this approach to an application, it is best to keep the most simple form of the data possible in the store, and combine that data in selector functions that return the aggregated data we require.

Taking the example above, we would have:

```
const state = {
    x: 3,
    y: 2,
    z: 5
}
```

and a selector function to calculate volume:

```
const selectVolume = state => state.x * state.y * state.z;
```

If the calculation is computationally expensive, then we can [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the selector function to avoid repeatedly calculating the same data:

```
const makeSelectVolume = () => {
    const memo = {};
    return state => {
        const (x, y, z} = state;
        // if we have memoized a value for these parameters return it
        if( x in memo && y in memo[x] && z in memo[x][y] ) {
            return memo[x][y][z];
        }
        // otherwise calculate it
        const volume = x * y * z;
        // and memoize it
        memo[x][y][z] = volume;
        return volume;
    }
}
```

Fortunately, the excellent library [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) creates automatically memoized selectors that we can use with redux, so we don't need to go to the trouble of memoizing them ourselves.  With reselect we would make our selector function like this:

```
const makeSelectVolume = () => createSelector(
    state => state.x,
    state => state.y,
    state => state.z,
    (x, y, z) => x * y * z
};
```

Now we just need to integrate this with our component:

```
// other imports as usual
import { makeSelectVolume } from 'path/to/selector';

const Volume = (props) => {
  if (props.volume === 'Infinity') {
    return (
      <Text
        style={{ ...formStyles.text, ...styles.text }}>
        Incalculable
      </Text>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <Text
        style={{ ...formStyles.text, ...styles.text }}>
        {props.volume + ' litres'}
      </Text>
    )
  }
}

Volume.propTypes = {
  volume: React.PropTypes.string
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    volume: makeSelectVolume()
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(Volume);
```

In your case just replace the volume calculation logic in the selector with your `calcVol` function.  Do note that it is imperative that `calcVol` is a pure function here i.e. it does not modify state in any way.

## Edit

If our state is an ImmutableJS map with the structure:

```
{
  widths: {
    width1: 2,
    width2: 7,
  },
  heights: {
    height1: 4,
    height2: 3
  }
}
```

We could write a selector function as either:

```
const makeSelectVolume = () => createSelector(
    state => state.get('widths'),
    state => state.get('heights'),
    (widths, heights) => calculateSomething(widths.toJS(), heights.toJS())
};
```

or as:

```
const makeSelectVolume = () => createSelector(
        state => state.get('widths').get('width1'),
        state => state.get('widths').get('width2'),
        state => state.get('heights').get('height1'),
        state => state.get('heights').get('height2'),
        (width1, width2, height1, height2) => calculateSomething({ width1, width 2 },{ height1, height2 })
    };
```

If you choose the second one then memoization will work fine, but if you choose the first one you may need to use reselect's [`createSelectorCreator`](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#createselectorcreatormemoize-memoizeoptions) to implement a custom equality checker.

Essentially reselect checks if any of the composed selectors values have changed, by default using `===` (which only returns true if they are literally the same object in memory).  If you return Immutable maps from your composed selectors then you will want to check if the maps are the same in terms of their values e.g. using the `equals` method of your Immutable maps:

```
import { createSelectorCreator, defaultMemoize } from 'reselect';

const createImmutableMapSelector = createSelectorCreator(
    defaultMemoize,
    (a, b) => a.equals(b)
);

const makeSelectVolume = () => createImmutableMapSelector(
    state => state.get('widths'),
    state => state.get('heights'),
    (widths, heights) => calculateSomething(widths.toJS(), heights.toJS())
};
```

This comes with some more complexity, but takes advantage of the speediness of Immutables deep comparisons.  Ultimately either way will work though.

Comment: Thanks this looks awesome. My state is an immutablejs map. To get my height from state I do `state.get('height').get('height1')` because it has nested heights. Will I transfer this way to get the height straight into your example in place of state.x?

Comment: Pretty much yes, but you can choose the granularity of the individual selectors that make up the whole to maximise memoization efficiency - I'll edit onto my answer with some code.

Comment: Done and working. Beautiful. I can completely remove my volume reducer. I used to have to use redux-thunk to call `calcVol(state)` every time I dispatch a width, length, thickness action and don't have to anymore. Thank you.